# Syntax error: Mixin columns takes 1 argument but 2 were passed

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm getting this error when trying to [compass compile]:

```
Syntax error: Mixin columns takes 1 argument but 2 were passed.
```

Everybody else on my team do not get this error. The offending line of code is:

```
@include columns(9,9);
```

Please assist.

Comment: How is your `columns` mixin actually declared?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson This is a compass mixing [http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/columns/]. In this documentation it does say that there is 1 argument but before changing anything I want to understand why it doesn't complain for other people.

Comment: Are you sure it's not complaining for "other people" because they're not using a comma to separate the values (eg. `@include columns(9 9)` instead of `@include columns(9, 9)`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, what fixed this problem is installing the [compass-susy-plugin] gem.